# Time Picker in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple drop down which shows the time slots in 24-hour format.
Example :

```
Select a time Slot 
--------------------
00 AM : 1:00 AM
--------------------
1:00 AM : 2:00 AM
--------------------
2:00 AM : 3:00 AM
--------------------
3:00 AM  : 4:00 AM
--------------------
4:00 AM  : 5:00 AM
--------------------
5:00 AM  : 6:00 AM
--------------------
-
-
-
-
--------------------
23:00 PM  : 24:00 AM
-------------------

So the above data come as array of objects :

[{"startTime" : "01","endTime":"02"},{"startTime" :"02" ,"endTime":"03"},{"startTime" :"03" ,"endTime": "04"},etc]


Now I have another array of objects , say availabilty slots :

[{"startTime" : "01","endTime":"02"},{"startTime" :"03" ,"endTime": "04"}]
```

Expectation: I would like to match both arrays of objects and in the list, the objects that get matched should be enabled and all others should be disabled.

Now how to compare both of these array objects and achieve this functionality?

Can Anyone please guide how to achieve this in React?

Comment: Where's the code that creates the dropdown? At least show us that so this doesn't have to be done from scratch

Comment: Hint: Use `Array#find()` on each item in main array to look in secondary array to see if same exists and set `disabled` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

While rendering your options with loop, you can determine if the current object is in your availability slot array. Then you can apply your enabled/disabled class accordingly.

See if below code helps.

```
const Dropdown = (slotArray=[], availabilityArr) => {
    return (
        <select>

             {
                 slotArray.map((currentSlot) => {
                     let isEnabled = availabilityArr.some((currAvailableSlot) => {currAvailableSlot.startTime === currentSlot.startTime && currAvailableSlot.endTime === currentSlot.endTime});

                     return (
                      <option value="yourValue" className={isEnabled? 'enabled-class': 'disabled-class'}>{currentSlot.startTime} to {currentSlot.endTime}</option>
                     )
                 });
             }
        </select>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a component `<Slot />` that renders a particular time slot:

```js
class Slot extends React.Component {
   static propTypes = {
      startTime: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      endTime: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      active: PropTypes.boolean.isRequired
   }

   render () {
      const { startTime, endTime } = this.props;
      return <option>
        ${startTime} : ${endTime}
      </option>;
   }
}
```

And a container class which receives your input data and renders the slots:

```js
class Picker extends React.Component {
   static propTypes = {
      allSlots: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      availableSlots: PropTypes.array.isRequired
   }

   render () {
      const { allSlots } = this.props;
      return allSlots.map(slot => <Slot>
         startTime={slot.startTime}
         endTime={slot.endTime}
      </Slot>);
   }
}
```

Then to take into account the available slots, you need to compare it against what your are currently rendering:

```js
   render () {
      const { allSlots, availableSlots } = this.props;
      return allSlots.map(slot => {
         const isAvailable = availableSlots.some(available => {
            return available.startTime === slot.startTime &&
                   available.endTime === slot.endTime
         }); // Compute 'isAvailable'
         return <Slot>
            startTime={slot.startTime}
            endTime={slot.endTime}
            active={isAvailable} // <-- Pass it down to the currently rendering `Slot`
         </Slot>;
      });
   }
```

And your `Slot` render function will look like:

```js
   render () {
      const { startTime, endTime, active } = this.props;
      return <option disabled={!active}>
        { startTime } : { endTime }
      </option>;
   }
```